# Given a Matrix A, prove that 1/9A is an orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

$$Let A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & -7 & 4 \\
        -1 & 4 & 8 \\
        -8 & -4 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

The problem is to prove that $1/9A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

**My Method:**

I found the dot products of all the columns of the matrix A:

$A_1 * A_2 = 0$

$A_1 * A_3 = 0$

$A_2 * A_3 = 0$

(Math was provided on the paper when I did out my work).

I concluded that since the columns in A are orthogonal to eachother- they form an orthogonal set and thus the matrix is orthogonal (because by definition a set is orthogonal if each pair of distinct vectors in the set is orthogonal). Since A is orthogonal, $1/9 A$ should be orthogonal as scalar multiplication should not change dot product values (ex: 1 + -1 = 0. If we multiply both by $1/2$ - that fact remains.

However the solution on this practice exam did things much differently. It's hard to follow their work- but they ended up taking the transpose of $1/9 A$ and simplifying into a triangular matrix which ended their proof.

Is my line of reasoning wrong? If so how? Can anyone help me understand how to fully answer this problem? My linear algebra exam is tomorrow and I thought I was prepared but this question has me second guessing myself.

Thanks!

Comment: An orthogonal matrix is one whose columns are *orthonormal*.

Comment: Ahh thanks. My professor didn't go over the definition for an orthogonal matrix so I only assumed we were supposed to use the definition for an orthogonal set and apply it to the set of vectors in the matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix is one which satisfies $A A^T = A^T A  = I$. That is, $A^{-1} = A^T$.

Equivliently, $A$ has orthonormal columns (and orthonormal rows). You've shown the columns are orthogonal for $A$, but each column of $A$ has norm 9. So, if you divide $A$ by 9, each column will still remain orthogonal to each other and then the columns will be normalized, so the columsn of $\frac{1}{9} A $ are orthonormal and thus $\frac{1}{9} A $ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is as simple as I think it is :

Let $ B = \frac{1}{9} A $ . Do the multiplication by each unit, calculate B and check if the columns and rows are orthogonal unit vectors. All this by supposing what you meant in the start was $ \frac{1}{9} A $/